# PHP - Code suddenly not updating mysql row

Tags: php, mysql

This code had been working for a while, but suddenly it doesn't without anything changing. The first part of the code is checking the user's credentials are correct. If they are, the data entered in the form is then submitted to the mysql and an email notification is sent. Here is the code:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $databaseName = "change_management";
    $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $passcode = $_POST['passcode'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '" . $user . "' and passcode ='".md5($passcode)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count ==0) {
    echo "
<font color=red><strong>Authentication failed - Invalid credentials</font></strong><br><br>";
    }
else {
    $change_id = $_POST['change_id'];
    $approval_disposition = $_POST['approval_disposition'];
    $approval_reason = $_POST['approval_reason'];
    $approval_impact = $_POST['approval_impact'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $approval_date = date('Y/m/d');
    $approval_expiry_date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime('+2 weeks'));

    $query = "UPDATE change_request_tbl SET approval_disposition='$approval_disposition', approval_reason='$approval_reason', approval_impact='$approval_impact', approval_name='$user', approval_date='$approval_date', approval_expiry_date='$approval_expiry_date' WHERE change_id='$change_id'";
    $query = "SELECT `change_requestor` FROM `change_request_tbl` WHERE `change_id` = $change_id";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))

    $to = "******, ****, ****, *****, $row[change_requestor]";
    $subject = "New Change Acceptance Board (CAB) Approval";
    $message = " 
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {font-family: Calibri;}
    body {font-style: italic;}
    .table {
    background-color: white;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Change Acceptance Board Approval</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>A new Change Acceptance Board (CAB) Approval has been submitted:</p>
    <table border=4 bordercolor=black class=table>
    <tr>
    <th>Change ID:</th>
    <th>Disposition:</th>
    <th>Reason for Rejection or Exceptions:</th>
    <th>Impact (By CAB):</th>
    <th>Approved/Rejected by:</th>
    <th>Date Approved:</th>
    <th>Approval Expiry Date*:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>$change_id</td>
    <td>$approval_disposition</td>
    <td>$approval_reason</td>
    <td>$approval_impact</td>
    <td>$user</td>
    <td>$approval_date</td>
    <td>$approval_expiry_date</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <p>*This change must be completed by the Expiry Date. If this is not achieved a second CAB Request must be raised referencing this Change ID.</p>
    </body>
    </html>";
    $headers = "MIME-Version:1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .='From: <******>' . "\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "
Your CAB Approval Form has been submitted. You will receive an email confirmation shortly.<br><br>";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

I am not getting any errors but I am getting the emails with the correct information. This issue lies solely with the update query. Any ideas why it has suddenly stopped working?

Comment: You could be sql-injecting yourself, for example a `'` in your input would do that. You really should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring `$query` two times, so you overwrite your `UPDATE` Query with the following `SELECT`.

Comment: Suddenly without changing anything :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "UPDATE change_request_tbl SET approval_disposition='$approval_disposition', approval_reason='$approval_reason', approval_impact='$approval_impact', approval_name='$user', approval_date='$approval_date', approval_expiry_date='$approval_expiry_date' WHERE change_id='$change_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

$query = "SELECT `change_requestor` FROM `change_request_tbl` WHERE `change_id` = $change_id";

$result1 = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
```

Sql queries valiable are overridden in the problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies here:

```
$query = "UPDATE change_request_tbl SET approval_disposition='$approval_disposition', approval_reason='$approval_reason', approval_impact='$approval_impact', approval_name='$user', approval_date='$approval_date', approval_expiry_date='$approval_expiry_date' WHERE change_id='$change_id'";

$query = "SELECT `change_requestor` FROM `change_request_tbl` WHERE `change_id` = $change_id";

$result1 = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
```

The UPDATE $query is overwritten by the subsequent SELECT $query, so it just selects the data but does not update it beforehand.

Comment: The results of the second query is needed as it contains an email address in which the information is sent. How to I modify the code to still achieve this?

Comment: Deepak below added the solution for you.